# What is the correct way to use Arrow Function with React native JSX element

Tags: react-native, arrow-functions

I'm having below code for my user profile and I have few questions about arrow function usage.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { Button } from 'native-base'
import AuthGlobal from '../../Context/store/AuthGlobal'

const UserProfile = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(AuthGlobal)

  const logoutHandler = (context) => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('auth')
    // call some method using context parameter
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            padding: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Button
            onPress={() => logoutHandler(context)}
          >
            <Text>
              Sign Out
            </Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

export default UserProfile
```

What is the optimal way to use the arrow function ?

1.

```
  const logoutHandler = (context) => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('auth')
    // call some method using context parameter
  }
```

```
           <Button
            onPress={() => logoutHandler(context)}
          >
            <Text>
              Sign Out
            </Text>
          </Button>
```

or 2.

```
  const logoutHandler = (context) => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('auth')
    // call some method using context parameter
  }
```

```
           <Button
            onPress={logoutHandler(context)}
          >
            <Text>
              Sign Out
            </Text>
          </Button>
```

I tried second option based on the fact that arrow functions are wasteful re-renders (https://blog.codemagic.io/improve-react-native-app-performance/) `Avoid Arrow Functions`. But in that case I'm getting this weird error  `ERROR    Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.`

Answer (score 1):

In case 2), you are not actually giving the Button component a function but you are calling the function logoutHandler and giving the result of this function call to the Button. This means that your function logoutHandler is called upon loading the JSX.

The Error probably results from the function logoutHandler causing a rerender, before the Button was rendered at all.

For optimization, you could do something like:

```
const buttonFunction = () => logoutHandler(context)
```

and use the buttonFunction as value for the Button.
Then, the 'function' would not rerender.
From personal experience, I would only optimize after the code is working and you feel that the performance is not enough for your application

Comment: In that case is case 1 the right approach ? and are there any performance drawbacks by using case 1 ?

Comment: Yes case 1 is the right approach. See Edited answer

Comment: Ok thanks, I did the implementation using case 1, But as I mentioned in the question I saw an article saying that calling arrow function inside a renderer gives performance issues. Thats why I tried case 2 and had this problem.

Comment: As per your edited answer , does that mean to pass like this `onPress={buttonFunction}` ?

Comment: Yes, that was my idea behind it. Then, the buttonFunction is created exactly once, which is the idea behind the optimization of the site you linked

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks.

Comment: The same approach should work for async function as well right ?  i.e. `const buttonFunction = async () => logoutHandler(context)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233355/discussion-between-john-stuart-and-philipp-p).